# Variable No Longer Exists after Creating Subrequest in Silex (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, silex

I have this issue where I'm attempting to create a subrequest in Silex and basically forward my parameters to another controllers. **Exhibit A** is broken below (after attempts to refactor), and **Exhibit B**, the original version, works:

**Exhibit A** (`$this->app` is lost after creating the request):

```
class EntriesController {
    private $app;
    private $req;

    public function __construct($app, $req) {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->req = $req;      
    }

    public function updateAction() {
        //...

            //$url defined here (eyesore-ingly long, so not shown)
            $subRequest = Request::create($url, 'GET', $params,  $this->req->cookies->all(), array(), $this->req->server->all());
            //$this->app **no longer** exists here
            return $this->app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

`EntriesController` instance is created below:

```
class AppControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface {
    public function connect(Application $app) {     
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

        //...

        $controllers->patch('/edit', function (Request $req) use ($app) {
            $entriesCtrl = new \EntriesController($app, $req);
            return $entriesCtrl->updateAction();                
        });

        //...
}
```

**Exhibit B** (works just fine):

```
 class AppControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface {
    public function connect(Application $app) {     
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

        $controllers->patch('/edit', function (Request $req) use ($app) {
            //...

            //$url defined here
            $subRequest = Request::create($url, 'GET', $params,  $this->req->cookies->all(), array(), $this->req->server->all());    
            return $this->app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
        }

        //...       
    });
```

I basically just reorganized the logic from **Exhibit B**'s `'PATCH' /edit` method body into a controller class, and I passed the Silex Application instance `$app` to a new instance of the controller class.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between Exhibit A and Exhibit B as far as I can tell is that you instantiate a controller object in the path method callback. Maybe there is something wrong with how this controller is setup or a namespace issue? Shootin' in the dark here.

I can confirm that in my silex application the following code does **not** produce a null $app container:

`GlobalControllerProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace Dev\Pub\Provider\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class GlobalControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

        $controllers
            ->get('/', 'Dev\Pub\Controller\GlobalController::indexAction')
            ->bind('homepage')
        ;

        $controllers
            ->patch('/edit', function (Request $req) use ($app) {
                $entriesCtrl = new \Dev\Pub\Controller\GlobalController();
                return $entriesCtrl->updateAction($app, $req);
        });

        return $controllers;
    }
}
```

`GlobalController.php`

```
<?php

namespace Dev\Pub\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class GlobalController
{
    public function indexAction(Application $app, Request $request)
    {
        return new Response($app['twig']->render('index.html.twig'));
    }

    public function updateAction(Application $app, Request $request)
    {
        $url = 'http://silex.local/index_dev.php/'; 
        $params = array();
        $subRequest = Request::create($url, 'GET', $params,  $request->cookies->all(), array(), $request->server->all());

        // outputs: 'Silex\Application'
        error_log(print_r(get_class($app),1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0); 

        // outputs: 1
        error_log(print_r(is_object($app),1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);  

        return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

`index.main.js`

```
$(function(){
    console.log('index.main.js');

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://silex.local/index_dev.php/edit",
        method: "PATCH"
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: I actually tried passing in `$app` and `$req` (updated the question above), but the same issue still exists.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. I am unable to reproduce the app container no longer existing.

Comment: It works now (for some reason, wasn't working previously when I was passing through `$app` and `$req`). I had put this off for a few days and came back to it because of your post. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you care to edit your answer a bit to explain why my original code didn't work and how to fix the issues, I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I still have no idea **why** your original code didn't work, all I can do is provide a working example and hope it helps.